# Partition input and execute queries in parallel

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, parallel.foreach

I have the following code where I want to retrieve employee information for a given list of employee ids. I have validation in place to throw exception if the count is more than 1 million. In most cases the request will be less than 200K so I am splitting the request into 4 partitions, each partition containing equal number of employee ids. All 4 partitions are executed in parallel and joined together after `Task.WhenAll`. Can some one please give me some hints on improving this further ? I looked at [ParallelForEachAsync](https://houseofcat.io/guides/csharp/parallel/parallelforeachasync) and [Parallel Foreach async in C#](https://medium.com/@alex.puiu/parallel-foreach-async-in-c-36756f8ebe62) but unable to make it to work. The code mentioned below works but its hard coded to split into 4 partitions. How do I make it more parallel with dynamic partitions with max degree of parallelism set to say 50? If the input is 100K ids, I want to split in 10 partitions and execute all 10 in parallel.

```
public class Service
{
    private async Task<List<EmployeeEntity>> GetInfo(List<long> input)
    {
        var breakup = input.Split(4);

        var result1Task = GetResult(breakup.First().ToList());
        var result2Task = GetResult(breakup.Skip(1).Take(1).First().ToList());
        var result3Task = GetResult(breakup.Skip(2).Take(1).First().ToList());
        var result4Task = GetResult(breakup.Skip(3).Take(1).First().ToList());

        await Task.WhenAll(result1Task, result2Task, result3Task, result4Task);

        List<EmployeeEntity> result1 = await result1Task;
        List<EmployeeEntity> result2 = await result2Task;
        List<EmployeeEntity> result3 = await result3Task;
        List<EmployeeEntity> result4 = await result4Task;

        return result1.Union(result2.Union(result3.Union(result4))).ToList();
    }

    private async Task<List<EmployeeEntity>> GetResult(List<long> employees)
    {
        using var context = new MyAppDBContext();
        var EmployeeBand = await context.EmployeeBand.Where(x => employees.Contains(x.EmployeeId)).ToListAsync();
        var EmployeeClient = await context.EmployeeClient.Where(x => employees.Contains(x.EmployeeId)).ToListAsync();
        return await context.Employee.Where(x => employees.Contains(x.EmployeeId)).ToListAsync();
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this List<T> myList, int parts)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var splits = from item in myList
                     group item by i++ % parts into part
                     select part.ToList();
        return splits.ToList();
    }
}

public class EmployeeEntity
{
    public EmployeeEntity()
    {
        EmployeeBands = new HashSet<EmployeeBandEntity>();
        EmployeeClients = new HashSet<EmployeeClientEntity>();
    }

    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeBandEntity> EmployeeBands { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeClientEntity> EmployeeClients { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeBandEntity
{
    public long EmployeeBandId { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public EmployeeEntity EmployeeEntity { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeClientEntity
{
    public long EmployeeClientId { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public EmployeeEntity EmployeeEntity { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyAppDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeEntity> Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeBandEntity> EmployeeBand { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeClientEntity> EmployeeClient { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tolist is the problem. You materialize the whole data set just to create the tasks. Input and output of `GetResult` should be `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: Often, db is the bottleneck. In your case that definitely could be the case. First you need to find out sweet spot for GetResult. What I mean by sweet spot is, why just end at 4 splits? Also, why not having splits dynamic based on your best possible performance of GetResult.

Comment: Improving it how? Do you need to do the parallelism? Why is the db not doing it for you/auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could be really creative about GetResult and rewrite in a better way so that queries are like `where id greater than (and/or less than)` rather than `ids in (... list)`. Assuming your GetResult is implemented in best possible way already and you simply need a way to achieve maximum parallel execution here is my solution.

```
private async Task<List<EmployeeEntity>> GetInfo2(List<long> input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (input.Count == 0)
    {
        return new List<EmployeeEntity>();
    }

    var taskList = new List<Task<List<EmployeeEntity>>>();

    foreach (var batch in input.Batch(100))
    {
        taskList.Add(GetResult(batch.ToList()));
    }

    var result = (await Task.WhenAll(taskList)).SelectMany(a => a);

    return result.ToList();
}
```

This requires following batch extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
        {
            T[] bucket = null;
            var count = 0;

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (bucket == null)
                    bucket = new T[size];

                bucket[count++] = item;

                if (count != size)
                    continue;

                yield return bucket.Select(x => x);

                bucket = null;
                count = 0;
            }

            if (bucket != null && count > 0)
                yield return bucket.Take(count);
        }
    }
```

You could find a sweet spot for size of batch. I've hardcoded it to 100 but you could derive it based on the size of input list or whatever other logic you may have.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will look into fine tuning the GetResults method. Your solution works great I am accepting it as the correct answer !

Comment: the foreach loop will spin up many tasks. I want to control the max degree of parallelism, how can that be achieved in your solution ?

Comment: @sravpk you'll need to use semaphore slim with desired max degree of parallelism. That SemaphoreSlim await one would go in your GetResult method. So GerResult won't be entered unless other locks are released

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative solution for managing tasks without having to write semaphoreslim thing I suggested for previous answer (in comments). I came across this .net out of box solution that uses `ActionBlock` from `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` namespace. This takes care of maintaining concurrency at the max degree required without using semaphore slim etc.

The `Batch` extension is still the same as per my previous answer. But for the first part you'd use `ActionBlock` like shown below (instead of `Task.WhenAll`).

```
        private async Task<List<EmployeeEntity>> GetInfo2(List<long> input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (input.Count == 0)
        {
            return new List<EmployeeEntity>();
        }

        var employeeEntities = new BlockingCollection<EmployeeEntity>();

        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<List<long>>(async (employeeIds) =>
        {
            var employees = await GetResult(employeeIds);
            employees.ForEach(e => employeeEntities.Add(e));
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            //config this to whatever works best in your situation
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20
        });

        foreach (var batch in input.Batch(100))
        {
            await actionBlock.SendAsync(batch.ToList());
        }

        actionBlock.Complete();
        await actionBlock.Completion;

        return employeeEntities.ToList();
    }
```